# Advantages and disadvantages of using beast-form to travel quicker on foot

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm traveling from Winterhold college to the Shrine of Azura - it's cold, I don't like (other) wolves and it takes ages. So I assumed the beast form because it can sprint way faster, and stamina regenerates at insane rates.

Is this a wise decision? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using beast form to travel faster? Do I need to kill people I meet to extend bloodlust, or can I kill a rabbit to continue?

<sub>Strangely, at the mine a 'fugitive' approached me and then asked me to store something. I was given two dialogue options (! as a werewolf) but could not do anything later.</sub>

Comment: I suggest changing "fast travel" to something else. "fast travel" is an in-game feature, that you don't seem to be referencing.

Comment: Note the fugitive "quest" is resolved almost immediately when someone comes looking for him 2 minutes later. The fugitive and his pursuer annoyed the heck out of me while I was facing a dragon, because they lock you out of commands until you finish speaking to them. (It has nothing to do with beast form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to avoid people and maintain blood lust, it's not a bad way to go.

You can maintain blood lust by feeding on the corpse of anything that would normally have blood: animals and humanoids both count.

You'll want to avoid people for two reasons:

- If they're particularly brazen (like a guard or fellow adventurer), they'll attack you on sight.
- If you can't maintain bloodlust until they go away, they'll see you transform and you'll be marked with a major crime.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to know how long bloodlust is going to last? Are there people who are not intimidated by the werewolf shout (Z-key)? Because even the most brave that I encountered made a 180 when I roared ever so slightly :')

Comment: @Konerak You should be able to see the duration under active powers in the Magic menu. I haven't found an NPC who's not responded to the howl.

Comment: Ehm - the magic menu is inaccessible during werewolf stage - or do you know a way around that?